# how to use isSuffixOf to test for two suffixes

Tags: haskell

So I have a list of strings say ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"], and I want to figure out which ones end with either "1" or "2".
I know I can use

```
map (isSuffixOf "1") ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
map (isSuffixOf "2") ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
```

to get two different list of bools, but is there any way I can test both at the same time? I tried these two variations

```
map (isSuffixOf "1" || "2") ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
map (isSuffixOf "1" || isSuffixOf "2") ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
```

but they both gave me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Arrows here.

```
import Control.Arrow

f = isSuffixOf "1" &&& isSuffixOf "2"
result = map (uncurry (||)) . map f $ ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
```

or, more simply, just write a list comp.

```
result = [isSuffix "1" x || isSuffix "2" x | x <- ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]]
```

or, even more simply, write a combinator of the two yourself.

```
anySuffixOf []     _ = False
anySuffixOf (x:xs) y = isSuffixOf x y || f xs y

result = map (anySuffixOf ["1", "2"]) ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a lambda expression to specify the mapping function

```
map (\x -> isSuffixOf "1" x || isSuffixOf "2" x) ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
```

Alternatively you can use the `Applicative` instance of `(->) a` to build the function

```
map ((||) <$> isSuffixOf "1" <*> isSuffixOf "2") ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
```

Or using `liftA2` (found in `Control.Applicative`)

```
map (liftA2 (||) (isSuffixOf "1") (isSuffixOf "2")) ["test1", "test2", "test3", "exam1"]
```